# The convenient way of the data storage in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and i  would like to know something

I want to store some types of big data in cassandra (boolean, text, double and so on). I would like to know how should i store all these data in Cassandra, all specified data type tables in one keyspace or one data type table in one keyspace?
For example **Some_Keyspace** (*boolean_table, text_table*...) or **Boolean_Keyspace**(*boolean_table*), **Text_Keyspace**(*text_table*)?

Which is better way to avoid overloading and don't decrease the reading and writing speed?

Thank you

Comment: Better approach will be model your tables based on query that will be used

Comment: Dear undefined_variable, thank you for your comment.

My problem is the convenient way of storage by view of speed and avoiding of overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the free courses on https://academy.datastax.com/courses
Start with the basics, then take a look at the course on data modelling which will explain how to structure your data.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

1) You should model your tables to fit your access patterns.

2) Replication Factor is configured by the keyspaces which could impact how you break up tables into keyspaces.

Based on your question, you should do a lot more reading around access patterns and data modeling in cassandra.

Comment: Dear Mr. Gerlt thank you for your answer.

Honestly i want to avoid overloading during writing and reading of big data. I said that I am new with Cassandra. I tried to find answer before writing my question here but i couldn't. It would be better if you share here some reading materials about my problem with your answer, otherwise your advise looks like famous joke about Winston Churchill and his driver